# What does `psql (14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1), server 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))` mean?

Tags: psql, wsl-2

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 within WSL2 and have recently just installed postgres on my WSL2 instance. I tried to connect to postgres, so I wrote `sudo -i -u postgres` and then `psql` to connect to the databases. Then I received the following that I do not understand:

`psql (14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1), server 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))`

It seems to me like there are two instances of postgres that are active - 14.1 and 12.9 - but I am not really sure. I also have postgres installed on my native Windows OS, so perhaps postgres is picking up both of them because of WSL 2?

Comment: that looks like build information

Comment: I guess what confuses me is that there’s two valid versions of postgresql there. 14.2 and 12.9 are both releases, so why it’s building two instances is odd to me.

Comment: The version of the `psql` executable you started has the version 14.1. The version of the server it connects to is 12.9 - that doesn't necessarily mean you have to "instances", just two different installations.